# Obter valor de radio button via jQuery e setar em um input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa noite, estou com um RadioGroup que me retornam três valores:
PM - Menor Peso (O menor peso entre o Peso de Saída e Peso de Chegada);
PS - Peso de Saída;
PC - Peso de Chegada;

O sistema deve pegar o valor do campo **PptMotorista** e então realizar o cálculo multiplicando pelo parâmetro selecionado acima e dividir o resultado por mil para ai sim exibir no campo de Frete Motorista.

```
            <div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">
            <label>PPT Motorista</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="170,00" name="PptMotorista" id="PptMotorista"/>
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 large-4 columns end">
            <label>Frete Motorista</label>
            <input type="number" name="FreteMotorista" id="FreteMotorista" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <fieldset class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
            <legend>Cálculo do Frete</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="calculoFrete" value="PM" id="menorpeso" required checked><label for="menorPeso">Menor Peso</label>
            <input type="radio" name="calculoFrete" value="PS" id="pesosaida"><label for="pesoSaida">Peso de Saída</label>
            <input type="radio" name="calculoFrete" value="PC" id="pesochegada"><label for="pesoChegada">Peso de Chegada</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var bPptMotorista   = document.getElementById( 'PptMotorista' );
    var bFreteMotorista = document.getElementById( 'FreteMotorista' );
    var bTipoPeso;
    var bRadioGroupPeso = '';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("*[name='calculoFrete']").change(function(){
            bRadioGroupPeso = ($(this).attr('value'));
        });
    });;

    if (bRadioGroupPeso == 'PS'){
        bTipoPeso = document.getElementById('PesoSaida');
    } else if (bRadioGroupPeso == 'PC') {
        bTipoPeso = document.getElementById('PesoChegada');
    } else {
        bTipoPeso = document.getElementById('PesoChegada') - document.getElementById( 'PesoTotal' );
    }

    bPptMotorista.onkeyup=calcula_frete;
    bTipoPeso.change=calcula_frete;

    function calcula_frete() {
        bFreteMotorista.value = ((bTipoPeso.value / 1000) * bPptMotorista.value);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Porém o código que escrevi, não sei porque não está pegando os valores, realizando o cálculo e jogando no Text do Frete Motorista. Alguém pode me ajudar e verificar se o código tem alguma coisa incorreta. 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

No seu script tem dois erros de sintaxe nas duas condicionais `if`, em JavaScript você deve colocar a condição entre parênteses, após a palavra `if`.

Mude para:

```
if (bRadioGroupPeso == 'PS') {
    bTipoPeso = document.getElementById('PesoSaida');
} else if (bRadioGroupPeso == 'PC') {
    bTipoPeso = document.getElementById('PesoChegada');
} else {
    bTipoPeso = (aPesoChegada.value - aPesoTotal.value);
}
```

Você também precisa declarar as variáveis var `aPesoChegada` e `aPesoTotal`.

Comment: As variáveis `aPesoChegda` e `aPesoTotal` elas estão em outra função, isso é válido? Ela está logo acima desta que descrevi na pergunta.

Comment: Se você declarou essas variáveis dentro de uma função, elas só são acessíveis dentro daquela função. Para usar a mesma variável em dois lugares, você pode declarar por exemplo no início do script, no escopo geral, fora de qualquer função.

Comment: Para um RadioGroup qual é o melhor evento que devo utilizar, acho que  o `bTipoPeso.onkeyup=calcula_frete` não irá funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Como você está usando jQuery, você pode usar o evento `change` (https://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: realizei algumas alterações no código, porém meu conhecimento com java script e jquery é muito vago.

Answer (score 0):

Nao vou realizar a logica para voce apenas vou te passar o basico para resolver, voce esta misturando os conceitos de jQuery e javascript, pra facilitar declarei o maximo possivel em jQuery.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var pptMotorista = $("#PptMotorista");  // Salva os seletores em variaveis
var freteMotorista = $("#FreteMotorista");

$("input[name=calculoFrete]").change(function() { // na mudanca do radio button
  var freteResultado = pptMotorista.val(); // Pega o valor do pptMotorista.
  if (this.value === 'PM') { // realiza o calculo se o valor do radio button for PM

  } else if (this.value === 'PS') { // idem mas se for PS

  } else if (this.value === 'PC') { // idem mas se for PC

  }
  freteMotorista.val(freteResultado); // Mostra no campo freteMorotista o resultado do calculo
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">
    <label>PPT Motorista</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="170,00" name="PptMotorista" id="PptMotorista" />
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns end">
    <label>Frete Motorista</label>
    <input type="number" name="FreteMotorista" id="FreteMotorista" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <fieldset class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
    <legend>Cálculo do Frete</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="calculoFrete" value="PM" id="menorpeso" required checked>
    <label for="menorPeso">Menor Peso</label>
    <input type="radio" name="calculoFrete" value="PS" id="pesosaida">
    <label for="pesoSaida">Peso de Saída</label>
    <input type="radio" name="calculoFrete" value="PC" id="pesochegada">
    <label for="pesoChegada">Peso de Chegada</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Veja o mesmo exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/dv87e68d/)

Recomendo dar uma lida no basico do jquery http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Dentro do `if (this.value === 'PM')` qual é a forma correta de realizar o cálculo? Tentei diversas formas e não consegui um resultado concreto. Ex: `freteResultado.val(((bPesoChegada - bPesoTotal)/ 1000) * pptMotorista.value);`

Comment: Nao estou vendo onde voce quer pegar esse bPesoChegada e bPeso total, mas voce deve colocalos no lugar dos valores igual nesse exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/dv87e68d/1/

Comment: Estou pegando da mesma forma que os exemplos acima que você me disse: `var bPesoSaida     = $("#PesoSaida");`